# EKS Admission Controller fails to call

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks, amazon-eks, kubernetes-apiserver

Hi I am attempting to create a set of dynamic admission webhooks (registry whitelisting, mostly for security context stuff). This is the [chart](https://github.com/mkm29/dp-image-admission-controller) that I am using, everything works fine when deployed to 2 other EKS clusters, but when I deploy it to a more secure cluster that we are setting up (using Bottlerocket OS among others things) I get the following error:

```bash
Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "...": failed to call webhook: Post "https://image-admission-controller-webhook.kube-system.svc:443/validate?timeout=2s": context deadline exceeded
```

I have verified that the service has an endpoint, the selector label maps to a pod, and that I am able to curl the above URL using a test curl image. What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: It is due to a SG rule, we are really trying to lock this VPC down

Answer (score 0):

Needed to allow a rule in the SG for the controlplane to allow 443 outbound from RFC1918